# Why is the letter "e" removed when changing some word's verb form to its noun form?

Tags: spelling

I came across a word which was encumber.

Like this verb there are many words  whose noun forms don't include e in that place (before r in that word). Is there any reason behind it or is it just an accepted usage?

For example:

- encumber -> encumbrance
- hinder -> hindrance

Comment: It would be useful if you provided more examples, the noun form you are referring to (I presume 'encumbrance'), and what attempts you have made to work out the answer for yourself.

Comment: @fred2 -- "encumber" becomes "encumbrance", "hinder" becomes "hindrance", *et cetera*.

Comment: This question might get better answers on the [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a property of the (spoken) language, not just of writing, and it's called [syncope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncope_(phonology)). It is a very common process across languages: a weak vowel before the final consonant of a word often disappears before an ending or suffix.

Examples:

> Latin *magister* 'master', plural *magistri*
>
> Russian *у́гол* (ugol) 'corner', plural *углы́* (ugly)
>
> Georgian *მეგობარი* (megobari) 'friend', plural *მეგობრები* (megobrebi) [the *-i* is the nominative suffix in either case: when the plural suffix *-eb* is added, the *-a-* disappears.]

It is usually not universal: in a given language, usually some words show it and others don't.